# Copy part of SVN repo to new repo?

Tags: svn, version-control

Currently, I have a large SVN repository with a bunch of different projects within it, as follows:

```
/
 Project1/
          trunk/
          tags/
          branches/
 Project2/
          trunk/
          tags/
          branches/
 Project3/ 
          (etc...)
```

However, I'm now trying to break it up into separate repositories (for various reasons), and I would like the following for each project:

```
/
 trunk/
 tags/
 branches/
```

If possible, all history and externals should remain intact. However, I'm unsure if this can actually be done. I have seen several questions similar to this on SO but none entirely addresses the issue I have here. Basically I am trying to "pull out" a subdirectory and its entire contents with history from the old repository and plop the whole lot into its own (new) repository.

Am I asking the impossible?

Comment: Great question +1. It must be possible. You'll probably have and aneurysm before the end though.

Comment: "Not programming related" -- J/K, I'm just getting annoyed with this type of comments, and need to blow off some steam :) +1 and fave'd :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
svnadmin dump path/to/repository > repo.dmp
```

and then use [svndumpfilter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svndumpfilter) to only load a subtree into a new repository.

Comment: Yeah... that's what I mean to say :)

Comment: Thank you Stefan (and John), this led me to http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering which addresses my exact problem.

Comment: Note that this solution leaves `ProjectN` as the top-level directory of the new repository. (I.e. all paths start with `ProjectN/`) THe link tells how to import the new repo without the prefix, but must edit the dump by hand, which with large repos or with binary files it's not practical.

Answer (score 5):

Since SVN 1.7 you could use

```
svnrdump dump path/to/repository > dump
```

to get the dump. While Stefans solution works, it does require access to the server hostig the repo.
svnrdump works over the net with any repo you can read from.