# SVN -Change directory structure on an existing repository

Tags: svn

Is is possable to change the directory structure of an existing SVN repository?

I have the following structure:

```
\trunk

\branches

\releases
```

I would like to change the \releases folder to \tags

Cheers
Sean

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No problem, use svn move. You can do the move locally and then do a checkin (it requires you to checkout the whole svn repository in this case).

You can also do the move remotely:

```
svn move svn+ssh:user@host//myrepo/releases svn+ssh:user@host//myrepo/tags
```

If you are using TortoiseSVN, you can do this action when browsing the repository.

Comment: Thanks, I used the repository browser on TortoiseSVN to rename the folder, didnt relise that it could be done from there.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do this on a working copy *that has all of those checked out from the root*, then the answers from Andrew and Artem are fine. Don't forget to commit the change!

I don't like to have all of my tags checked out, so in that case, you would need to use URL parameters.

For example:

```
svn move svn://svnmachine/repository/release svn://svnmachine/repository/tags
```

FYI: `mv`, `rename`, `move`, and `ren` are all the same command, which are equivalent to a `copy` and `delete`.

[Help on svn move command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html)

Answer (score 4):

Sure - they're just directories. Just do

```
svn move releases tags
```

or use a visual SVN client to do the moving, like SmartSVN

Comment: This does require a working copy with releases and tags as sub-folders, as well as a commit afterwards

Comment: I don't understand SO sometimes, I answer a question first, somebody else later responds saying exactly the same thing I do, and then they get upvoted. :)

Comment: I actually prefer checking out, doing things, then checking in because 1. You can make multiple changes and commit in one go and 2. You will see the changes done before they go live

Comment: Andrew, maybe they think you smell bad :) or someone is a fan of SmartSVN, like me.

Answer (score 2):

```
svn mv releases/ tags/
svn commit -m "move releases/ to tags/"
```

Then if you want to recreate the releases folder

```
svn mkdir releases
svn commit -m "recreate releases folder"
```

Answer (score 1):

The "rename" command is probably what you need. It will keep revision history and allow you to change directories of files.

Comment: Funny, I gave this answer to another question a while back which I had misread as being pretty much this quesion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009314/copy-part-of-svn-repo-to-new-repo/1009343#1009343

Comment: rename and move is the same thing

Comment: Is it? Perhaps I was confusing move with "relocate".